# Applescript: "Can’t get group 1 of window \"Control Center\" of application process \"ControlCenter\". Invalid index."

Tags: applescript

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell its application process "ControlCenter"
        tell its menu bar 1
            click its menu bar item "User"
        end tell
        
        tell its window "Control Center"
            tell its group 1
                set btns to its buttons
                repeat with btn in btns
                    if name of btn = "BrilliantCorners" then
                        click btn
                    end if
                end repeat
            end tell
        end tell
        
        delay 1
        set thePassword to "mypassword" -- Mac user password
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "SecurityAgent"
                set value of text field 1 of window "Login" to thePassword
                key code 36
            end tell
        end tell
        
    end tell
end tell
```

error "System Events got an error: Can’t get group 1 of window "Control Center" of application process "ControlCenter". Invalid index." number -1719 from group 1 of window "Control Center" of application process "ControlCenter"

This script worked just fine before I upgraded to Monterey, now it's getting stuck for some reason I can't figure out. Any ideas?

Comment: It's getting "stuck" because you're trying to address an invalid object with GUI Scripting.  You're going to have to redevelop your script and determine the new reference for the object(s).  GUI scripting is brittle, you have no guarantee that from even minor version to minor version, object references do not move.

Comment: Any recommendation on how I might determine the new object reference, or where to even start looking? I'm new to scripting and trying to learn how it works. This script is something I pieced together from a few similar scripts I found online - if Monterey changed the object reference and I had to figure out how to incorporate that new reference into the script... well I wouldn't even know where to start looking for that. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **macOS Monterey**, using the **AppleScript** *code* in your question, I was able to get it to work by removing the `tell its group 1` *statement* and its closing `end tell` *statement*, e.g.:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell its application process "ControlCenter"
        tell its menu bar 1
            click its menu bar item "User"
        end tell
        
        tell its window "Control Center"
                set btns to its buttons
                repeat with btn in btns
                    if name of btn = "BrilliantCorners" then
                        click btn
                    end if
                end repeat
        end tell
```

**Notes:**

The **AppleScript** *code* shown herein is just a *snippet* of your original *code* and does not show the remaining working *code* as tested.

Comment: You are an absolute life saver. Pretty sure I even tried that but forgot to delete the corresponding end tell... working perfectly now, thank you very very much

Comment: I'm having a similar error in getting this previously working [Bluetooth Applescript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/430580/applescript-error-can-t-get-group-1-of-window-control-center) to run on macOS Monterey. Feedback is much appreciated!